# How to whiten a white Ikea mattress cover?

Tags: washing-machine, bedroom

The cover of [my mattress](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/malfors-foam-mattress-medium-firm-white-00272289/) has gone grayish and yellowish, it looks bad. But on Ikea's website it says "do not bleach".

Is there still a way to make it more white? Perhaps not as white as it once was, but at least presentable?

**Details:**

100% polyester
Polyester wadding
Non-woven polypropylene
Machine wash
max 60°C, normal process. Do not bleach. Do not tumble dry. Do not iron. Do not dryclean

Comment: Take it to a laundry professional or buy a replacement.

Comment: Put a sheet over it and ignore the colouration as long as its comfortable :)

Comment: This is about laundering, not home improvement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Clorox2, or Hydrogen Peroxide, or Sodium Percarbonate or Oxyclean, (it's all the same stuff) instead of chlorine bleach.   Chlorine bleach reacts with some brighteners to turn them yellow or purple.

Comment: James and Ted have it:  Oxyclean or similar non-bleach whitener is what you want!

Comment: @markf I think "non-chlorine" is a better description than "non-bleach", since Oxyclean etc. are also bleaches.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I guess from my HS chemistry I always considered Chlorine to be always  NaClO, but the broader definition may be  "any whitening cleaner", like the hydrogen peroxide based oxyclean

Comment: @TedMittelstaedt I can only find Oxiclean on Amazon (UK) but it's expensive. Perhaps the other ones you mention are cheaper, any idea how to find them on Amazon?

Comment: Hydrogen Peroxide from the druggist will also act as a bleach.  However it has to be fresh - when it goes stale it basically turns into water.

Answer (score 5):

We used a 'white repair' type laundry product, bought from the local supermarket. It is specifically for whitening rather than colour runs. It worked very well.

It contains sodium carbonate peroxyhydrate or 'oxygen based bleaching agents', very different from chlorine bleach.